# GRUB installed without installing Linux

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, windows

Ok so this is very weird:

I made some live-USB for some Ubuntu installations and accidently put them in one of my partitions (which conviently was the same size as my flash drive so  I didn't notice). Now when I turn on my PC I get greeted by a GRUB screen without nothing to boot into, I tried to boot up to a live CD and deleted the files from the partition, now I get another screen that says GRUB is missing or something like that. I looked around and I found that I can probably use a Windows Recovery CD and run bootrec /fixmbr, but is there anyway I can fix this from the Ubuntu Live USB I have?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, you should just be able to select Windows from UEFI boot menu.  If BIOS, Boot-Repair can restore a Windows type boot loader to MBR. Just add it to your Ubuntu live installer. Or use your Windows repair flash drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Or: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on/422023#422023

Comment: Got a hold of a recovery CD, though still had some troubles finally figured it out for some reason the Partition I accidently installed my Linux USB, became volume C: and the PC didn't even try to boot from the partition my Windows was installed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Its ok simply install another OS it will overwrite grub

Answer (score 0):

Got a hold of a recovery CD, though still had some troubles finally figured it out for some reason the Partition I accidently installed my Linux USB, became volume C: and the PC didn't even try to boot from the partition my Windows was installed.

If anyone gets in my kind of situation:
You need to  run bcdboot -s E: c:/windows (or whatever volume is assigned to your Windows partition) and then bootrec /fixmbr.
You can find out the Volumes by using diskpart:
list volumes

Answer (score 0):

Boot Loader actually remains until its overwritten by another boot loader. You can experience this in incomplete installation or when you install operating system in another boot option (UEFI or Legacy) with full disk image but you by mistake boot on the other option where previous OS was installed you will see the grub but not the OS.